# Starting multiple windows workflows

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow-foundation

I'm completely new to Windows Work Flow...but the company that I joined recently has several modules that uses Windows Workflow and I'm assigned to support this application.

We have been bothered by a strange problem in windows work flow in our Performance Reviews Module (Appraisals).

Below is the test scenario.

I open my performance review in one internet explorer tab.(One work flow has started at the backend).
Now I open another user's performance review in the second tab (Another work flow has started)

(Name of employee, employee goals, comments etc are stored in the persistance store in sql server)

Now, when I save my performance review - all the data from the persistance store of the 2nd tab gets saved into my performance review!!!

Why this occurs?

Currently we have restricted the users to open only one performance review at a time.
But it causes more troubles. So I kind of want to lift the restrictions and fix the core issue with the work flow.

Comment: Sorry. It had nothing to do with the work flow infact...it was the session that created the whole misery. Question closed! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry..it had nothing to do with the work flow infact. It was the session that was causing problems...:)